# How to fix unable to create order issue in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

During checking out I'm facing this issue **Unable to create order**.
My wordpress version is *5.9.1* and woocommerce version is *5.9.0*.

But the strange thing is, in my localhost I can create order but in live it is showing that message. My local wordpress version is *5.5* and woocommerce version is *4.4.1*.

There is no JS error into my frontend. Somehow I can't provide my frontend URL here because the site is now password protected. In live admin panel, I see woocommerce message in admin notice that it says "Woocommerce database update required". Should I press the button to update my wordpress database? Also I've seen my wp_posts table's post_password's field length is 255 varchar. Because I read in another article, that field can be 20 character length in older version of wordpress and need to increase the length size but in my case I see it is already in 255 length. So could anyone provide me any suggestion to fix it?

Moreover, I see few woocommerce templates are in out of date in my woocommerce status.

Those are:

```
ctp_2020/woocommerce/cart/mini-cart.php version 3.7.0 is out of date. The core version is 5.2.0
ctp_2020/woocommerce/checkout/form-pay.php version 3.4.0 is out of date. The core version is 5.2.0
ctp_2020/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php version 3.8.0 is out of date. The core version is 5.2.0
ctp_2020/woocommerce/emails/email-addresses.php version 3.9.0 is out of date. The core version is 5.6.0
ctp_2020/woocommerce/emails/plain/email-addresses.php version 3.4.0 is out of date. The core version is 5.6.0
ctp_2020/woocommerce/emails/plain/email-order-items.php version 3.7.0 is out of date. The core version is 5.2.0
ctp_2020/woocommerce/order/order-details-customer.php version 3.4.4 is out of date. The core version is 5.6.0
ctp_2020/woocommerce/order/order-details-item.php version 3.7.0 is out of date. The core version is 5.2.0
ctp_2020/woocommerce/order/order-details.php version 3.7.0 is out of date. The core version is 4.6.0
ctp_2020/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/grouped.php version 4.0.0 is out of date. The core version is 4.8.0
ctp_2020/woocommerce/content-product_cat.php version 2.6.1 is out of date. The core version is 4.7.0
ctp_2020/woocommerce/taxonomy-product_cat.php version 1.6.4 is out of date. The core version is 4.7.0
ctp_2020/woocommerce/taxonomy-product_tag.php version 1.6.4 is out of date. The core version is 4.7.0.
```

I've updated those as well but no luck.

Please have a look at my screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've solved it.
The reason is, some of tables were not set **auto_increment** constrain.
After altering those tables it is solved.
Why Woocommerce tables structure changed because we moved our correct database from one database to another database. During exporting and importing it happend something wrong with the SQL. Anyway now it is fixed.